# Registering custom events in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, event-listener, custom-events

I am new to the world of React.

Is there a way to register a custom event in the child component and pass the data to the component from its parent component? I know we can pass params through props or state but I am looking something related to events.

Example:

**Child Component:**

```
const onCustomEvent = (data) =>{
    console.log("Custom event called from parent",data)
}
```

**Parent Component:**

fire that `onCustomEvent()` from parent

Comment: @devesh.you can try redux state management

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)